# VimTeX - latexmk: -reuse-instance bad option. Any suggestions?

Tags: latexmk, vim

I'm trying to set up a Vim and LaTeX system on my Windows machine, but keep running into the same compilation issue. My setup consists of `vim` (via Git for Windows), lervag's VimTeX (via vim-plug), `latexmk` (via MikTeX) and SumatraPDF. Everything is installed correctly, is up-to-date and work fine on their own, but every time I execute `:VimtexCompile` or `<leader>ll` in a TeX document, I get the same `latexmk` error:

```
VimTeX: Compiler did not start successfully!
```

```
Latexmk: -reuse-instance bad option
Unquoted string "echo" may clash with future reserved word at (eval 10) line 1.
Unquoted string "echo" may clash with future reserved word at (eval 11) line 1.
Rc files read:
  NONE

Latexmk: Bad options specified
Use
   latexmk -help
to get usage information
```

`-reuse-instance` is indeed a bad option for `latexmk`, but somewhere deep in a VimTex script, that argument must be being used. I've tried updating Git for Windows and reinstalling both VimTeX and `latexmk`, but no luck so far.

This is my `.vimrc` file:

```
call plug#begin('(path to vimfiles)\\vimfiles\\plugged')

Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
"Other plugins

call plug#end()

let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
       \ 'executable' : 'latexmk',
       \ 'options' : [
       \   '-pdf',
       \   '-file-line-error',
       \   '-synctex=1',
       \   '-interaction=nonstopmode',
       \ ],
       \}

let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer = 'SumatraPDF'
let g:vimtex_view_general_options
    \ = '-reuse-instance -forward-search @tex @line @pdf'
let g:vimtex_view_general_options_latexmk = '-reuse-instance'
```

Any thoughts on what the culprit could be? Any suggestions?

Robert

Comment: This is does not obviously solve your problem, but gives you the same IMHO: since you are using latexmk, why should you call it from Vim? Just run it as a separate process on your shell. I’ve not been using `latexmk` for a while so I can't remember its options name, but you can ask latexmk to check regularly if your .tex file changed since last check, and if so compile automaticaly.

Comment: `-reuse-instance` is an option to be passed to SumatraPDF but not latexmk (or latex/pdflatex for that matter).  The last line of your configuration looks as if you have specified `-reuse-instance`  as an option to latexmk. You'd have to look at the lervag/vimtex documentation to be sure what to do.  I wonder whether simply removing the last line of `.vimrc` would work.  You could also configure SumatraPDF to do reuse instance without  needing to use the command line option---see the SumtraPDF documentation.